# Is there a way to get data in organized form from sqlite db?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord, discord.py

So I have a sqlite database that has all the users in my server and each user's xp (just like any other leveling system). is there a way to send the top 10 people from the db to discord? in an organized manner, because I'm getting it in this form.

```py
[(722267777854865519, 9877, 20),
 (356982883665051659, 8039, 17),
 (746740254173560853, 7358, 17),
 (750497624809013248, 7054, 16),
 (605861925749915752, 6757, 16)]
```

And is there a way to get it to mention the user rather than sending their ids?

(P.S. the first value is the user's discord id, 2nd is their xp and 3rd is their level)

by organized form I mean,

1. user 1 mention(not the user id) - XP - level
2. user 2 mention(not the user id) - XP - level
3. etc etc till 5.

this is the code

```
    @commands.command()
    async def lb(self,ctx):
        records = db.records("SELECT UserID, XP, Level FROM exp ORDER BY XP DESC LIMIT 5")

        await ctx.send(records)
```

Comment: If you want to get help, you will have to provide more detail. how do you get this data? please provide at least a chunk of code, a runnable code would be better. What "organized form" are you looking for? please provide an example of what you want. Unless you provide this, you will probably not get any valuable answer and your question will potentially be marked as "to be closed".

Comment: is it better now? or anything else I have to add? @Tryph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Is there a way to get the top 10 people?

Sort your list & take the first 10 entries.

```
records.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
for user in records[:10]:
# do_something_with_them
```

- Can I get it to mention the user instead of sending the id's?

Yes, you can first get the `user` instance of that person, and then get it's `mention` attribute (which will return a string of the format `<@!id>`), and send that instead.

```
user_id = 722267777854865519
user = client.get_user(user_id)
await ctx.send(user.mention)
```

EDIT: Seeing as you just edited your post, asking for precise info on how to do the formatting:

Formatting it like you need to is just a matter of creating a string of your desired format by iterating over your records in a `for-loop`.

```
leaderboard = []
for i, user in enumerate(records[:10]):
    leaderboard.append(f"{i + 1}. {client.get_user(user[0]).mention} - {user[1]} XP - Level {user[2]}")
await ctx.send("\n".join(leaderboard))
```

Do keep in mind that mentioning everyone every single time might be really annoying for them, and you should probably place this inside of an `embed` as those do highlight their name (like normal mentions, so you can click on them), but don't mention the users.

Comment: instead of mentioning, is there a way to just display the name tag and not mention the user?

Comment: If you only want their display name, use `.display_name` instead of `.mention`, this will return their name as a string. You won't be able to click on it to go their profile though, if you still want to be able to do that then I've explained that in my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop to separate the data into their respective positions.

```
@client.command()
async def leaderboard(ctx):
    data = [(722267777854865519, 9877, 20), (356982883665051659, 8039, 17), (746740254173560853, 7358, 17), (750497624809013248, 7054, 16), (605861925749915752, 6757, 16)]
    for thing in data:
        user = thing[0]
        user_xp = thing[1]
        user_level = thing[2]
        print(f"Member: {user}\nLevel: {user_level}\nXP: {user_xp}")
```

Output:

```
Member: 722267777854865519
Level: 20
XP: 9877
Member: 356982883665051659
Level: 17
XP: 8039
Member: 746740254173560853
Level: 17
XP: 7358
Member: 750497624809013248
Level: 16
XP: 7054
Member: 605861925749915752
Level: 16
XP: 6757
```